# extract database information with Recursively in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have table structure in database like this:
menuId, label, parentMenuId
like a category and sub category how to extract this data in this method:
all menu into one array:
i want to extract all related menu in one array list like this.

```
array(
    [0] => array(array(1,php), array(2,c#), array(3,asp), array(4,perl)),
    [0] => array(array(5,c++), array(6,android), array(7,java), array(8,tcl)),
    ...
    ...
    ...
)
```

all the item in this array are related.
for example, php is parent of c# and c# parent of asp and asp parent of perl, all this related item want to extract in one array.

Comment: post you code and a sample of your database. that way we have something to work with.

Comment: thanks for your efforts at making what you wanted clearer. it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
$result = array();
$menu_items = array(array("php", "c#", "asp", "perl"),array("vb", "java", "android", "c++"));
foreach($menu_items as $menu_item) {
  foreach($menu_item as $item) {
    array_push($result, $item);
  }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: no, i have a database with three field(id, title, parentId) want to create the array i mention in above from this structure with recursilevy.

Answer (score 0):

I use 'redbeanphp' as the database 'orm' of choice as it uses PDO and defines all the tables automatically. makes using a database fun.

It is important to note that 'readbeanphp' just does the database handling. You can substitute all the 'stores' and 'finds' with the 'mysqli' or 'pdo' ones. 'redbeanphp' is just a layer that translates the calls to PDO automatically. If also automates some of the queries as regards fetching related records. just saves us having to code them manually. It generates the exact same code that you do manually.

Here is the tested code to save and return a menu tree with nested menus.

The code can be downloaded and includes 'redbeanphp': **[Q23418814.zip](http://ge.tt/1GkWtaf1/v/0?c)**

1) Create the menu as an array:

```
// let us create a menu as we want it to look -- with nested submenus
$menu1Submenus = array( array('PHP', 'C#',
                                array('lisp', 'logo'),
                                'asp', 'perl'),
                 array('c++', 'android', 'java', 'tcl'),
               );
```

2) connect to the database and define a constant for the 'bean'.

```
require_once __DIR__ .'/RedBeanPHP4/rb.phar';
\R::setup("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testmysql", 'test', 'test', false);

define('BEAN_MENUITEM', 'menuitem');

// redbeanphp automatically provides an 'id' for every 'bean'
//
// It will automatically make the foreign key fields
//
// all fields must be lowercase

// clear the table
$result = \R::exec('delete from menuitem');
```

3) Define a 'parent' for the entire menu as a bean that we can store in the database. The database table will be automatically created.

```
//the owner of the complete menu
$menu1 = \R::dispense(BEAN_MENUITEM);
$menu1->label = 'menu1';
\R::store($menu1);
```

4) Add the complete menu to to the database

```
// add the complete submenus and the items to the database...
foreach($menu1Submenus as $submenu) {
    addSubmenu($menu1, $submenu);
}

echo 'menu stored.';
```

5) Retrieve the menu from the database by getting the 'parent' bean then 'tree walk' it.

```
$parentList = \R::find(BEAN_MENUITEM, " label = ? limit 1", array('menu1'));
if (empty($parentList)) {
    die('menu parent not found!');
}
$parent = current($parentList);

$menu2 = getSubmenu($parent);
```

6) show the outputs:

```
var_dump($menu1Submenus, 'original',  $menu2, 'from database');
exit;
```

Now, you need the routines that add to the database:

```
function addSubmenu($parent, $itemList = array())
{
    if (empty($itemList)) {
        return;
    }

    // make an owner for the submenu
    $smOwner = \R::dispense(BEAN_MENUITEM);
    $smOwner->label = 'parent:'. $parent->id;
    $parent->ownMenuitem[] = $smOwner; // sets the foreign key relationship
    \R::store($parent);

    foreach($itemList as $label) {
        if (is_array($label)) { // nested submenu, recurse...
            addSubmenu($smOwner, $label);
            continue; // process next entry...
        }
        $bean = \R::dispense(BEAN_MENUITEM);
        $bean->label = $label;
        $smOwner->ownMenuitem[] = $bean;
        \R::store($smOwner);
    }
}
```

And retrieve from the database...

```
function getSubmenu($parent, $menuList = array())
{
    $ml = $menuList;

    foreach($parent->ownMenuitem as $entry) {
        if (isSubmenu($entry)) {
            $sm  = array();
            $ml[] = getSubmenu($entry, $sm);
            continue;
        }
        $ml[] = $entry->label;
    }
    return $ml;
}
```

And any 'helpers'

```
function isSubmenu($menuitem)
{
    return strpos($menuitem->label, 'parent:') !== false;
}
```

The database output for the example:

```
    id  label     menuitem_id  
------  --------  -------------
     1  menu1            (NULL)
     2  parent:1              1
     3  PHP                   2
     4  C#                    2
     5  parent:2              2
     6  lisp                  5
     7  logo                  5
     8  asp                   2
     9  perl                  2
    10  parent:1              1
    11  c++                  10
    12  android              10
    13  java                 10
    14  tcl                  10
```